# avr-libc and stdio.h - Function-like macro leads to error: expected unqualified-id before 'do'

Tags: c++, macros, syntax-error, avr, preprocessor

I'm working with avr-libc, and need to use a function-like macro defined in the [stdio.h](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/stdio_8h_source.html) header of the library:

```
#define fdev_setup_stream(stream, p, g, f) \
do { \
(stream)->put = p; \
(stream)->get = g; \
(stream)->flags = f; \
(stream)->udata = 0; \
} while(0)
```

in my code, I create a FILE buffer, and try to prepare it with the macro:

```
void uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream) {
    if (c == '\n') {
        uart_putchar('\r', stream);
    }
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = c;
}

FILE uart_output;
fdev_setup_stream(uart_output, uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
<path_to_file>/foo.cpp:80:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'do'
fdev_setup_stream(uart_output, uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
^
<path_to_file>/foo.cpp:80:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'while'
fdev_setup_stream(uart_output, uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
^
```

Why doesn't the compiler allow the macro definition? Why wouldn't the syntax be correct?

I'm compiling with avr-g++ version 4.9.2, and using the -std=gnu++11 flag. In Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You can't have general statements (like a `do ... while(...)` loop) outside of functions.

Comment: You can write simple function and make define just for calling the function. Additionaly, I'm not sure that you can invoke uart_putchar without an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! You were spot on; I was accidentally calling the macro outside my main function. Moving the macro calls to main fixed the issue. If you'd just want to type this into an answer, I would gladly accept..!